# Finding right item by given input and output extention (Path Finding)

Tags: c#, path-finding

I am working on a file converter project. So I will get "input extention" and "output extension" from the user and then, i have to find which converter(s) module must be used.

I have some modules that convert different file formats. For example, word module can convert several file formats to another file formats, it is the same for excel, pdf, powerpoint etc.

So here is my list

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, SupportedFormats> _supportedFormats=new Dictionary<string, SupportedFormats>();

public static Dictionary<string, SupportedFormats> GetSupportedAppsWithFormats()
{
  if (_supportedFormats.Count == 0)
  {
    var tmpSupportedFormats = new SupportedFormats();
   tmpSupportedFormats.InputFormats = new List<string>() {"DOC","DOCX","RTF","DOT","DOTX","DOTM","XML","ODT","OTT","HTML","MHTML","TXT"};
   tmpSupportedFormats.OutputFormats = new List<string>() { "PDF", "XPS", "PS","SVG", "EMF", "JPG", "PNG", "BMP", "TIFF" };
 _supportedFormats.Add(AppId.Word, tmpSupportedFormats);

   tmpSupportedFormats = new SupportedFormats();
   tmpSupportedFormats.InputFormats = new List<string>() { "XLS","XLSX","XLSB","XLTX","XLTM","ODS","CSV","HTML","MHTML" };
  tmpSupportedFormats.OutputFormats = new List<string>() { "PDF", "XPS", "SVG", "EMF", "JPG", "PNG", "BMP", "TIFF" };
  _supportedFormats.Add(AppId.Excel, tmpSupportedFormats);

  tmpSupportedFormats = new SupportedFormats();
  tmpSupportedFormats.InputFormats = new List<string>() { "PDF", "XPS", "EPUB", "HTML", "MHT", "TEX", "CGM", "XSLFO", "XML","PCL","SVG" };
 tmpSupportedFormats.OutputFormats = new List<string>() {"PDF", "DOC", "DOCX", "XLS", "PPTX", "JPG", "PNG", "BMP", "TIFF"};
_supportedFormats.Add(AppId.Pdf, tmpSupportedFormats);

tmpSupportedFormats = new SupportedFormats();
tmpSupportedFormats.InputFormats = new List<string>() { "PPT", "PPTX", "PPS", "PPSX", "PPTM", "PPSM", "POTX", "POTM", "ODP"};
tmpSupportedFormats.OutputFormats = new List<string>() { "PDF", "XPS", "JPG", "PNG", "BMP", "TIFF", "HTML" };
_supportedFormats.Add(AppId.PowerPoint, tmpSupportedFormats);

 tmpSupportedFormats = new SupportedFormats();
 tmpSupportedFormats.InputFormats = new List<string>() { "BMP", "JPG", "TIF" ,"TIFF", "GIF", "PNG", "PSD", "EMF", "WMF", "PDF", "DJVU" };
tmpSupportedFormats.OutputFormats = new List<string>() { "BMP", "JPG", "TIFF", "GIF", "PNG", "PSD", "EMF", "WMF" };
_supportedFormats.Add(AppId.Image, tmpSupportedFormats);

   .....

  }      
    return _supportedFormats;
}
```

Well, let say my input extention is DOC and output is HTML then I will need

AppId.Word , AppId.Pdf and AppId.PowerPoint.

Because Word converter will convert doc to pdf and then pdf converter will take this pdf file and will convert to PPTX and then powerpoint converter will convert pptx to html.

I am looking for input and outputformats of the supportedformats. For example the doc converter has ability to convert DOC,DOCX,RTF.. to PDF,XPS,PS.. 
So when i create this path, i need to look input-output formats

So I need to find these relations among them.

Thousands files will come to be converted and I need to consider performance issue. I can make it somehow with loop and maybe recursive method but not sure whether it will be the best approach.

Comment: create a graph where every file type is a node and every link is a conversion between the two connected types. then just plan a route. if the amount of routes is small in comparison to the amount of converted files be sure to cache the routes. And don't use recursion if you can reasonably avoid it, you are writing C# not haskell.

Comment: Also look into Intermediate Representations. Cross-compilers such as LLVM use them in order to reduce conversions. If this project is for school, you may not have the time to implement one, but it is worth using for any project without time constraints. It also alleviates the need to pathfind.